# How to prevent from "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" while linq selecting columns lists of latest records by grouping?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Couldn't getting any records.Throwing an error :

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   DAL.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information:
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Considering the following records:

```
Id          No            createdDate    Extension
 --------------------------------------------------
   1           9000          1990           10
   2           9000          1990           11
   3           9000          2000           12
   4           9849          2001           1
   5           9849          2002           2 
   6           9700          2010           4

var res = from cust in Customers
                      group cust by cust.No
                        into groups
                       select groups.OrderByDescending(p => p.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

where as this same concept applying in Controller action methode like below.Then not getting any null error, getting records as per my requirement.

```
var result = from refC in _objRefCustomerBS.GetAllRefCustomer()
                         group refC by refC.MobileNo into grp
                         select grp.OrderByDescending(g => g.cuRefID).FirstOrDefault();
```

I want to group by based on the `No` field and sort by `Id` and get all fields from the last record of group similar to these records:

```
Id          No            createdDate    Extension
 -------------------------------------------------  
   3           9000          2000           12   
   5           9849          2002           2 
   6           9700          2010           4
```

Comment: lambda version : var res = Customers.GroupBy(x => x.No).Select(x=>x.ToList().OrderByDescending(y=>y.Id).First()).ToList();

Comment: @Mehrdad Dowlatabadi I updated as per your query its same exception throwing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem I see in your query is that you assign **cust** as the variable name for items in `Customers` but then you group **element** which I'm not even sure what is as it's not declared within the code snippet you provided.

So, fix the naming and you should be good to go:

```
var res = from cust in Customers
        group cust by cust.No
        into groups
        select groups.OrderByDescending(p => p.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: sorry here I mistake written element at cust side..but in my code is same...